# Why do I get Error in Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `medication_name`. x Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 2

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a data set with another with a list of a nested data.

```
    age_pharma <-  structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), age_band = c("5_9", 
"10_14", "15-19", "20-24", "5_9", "10_14", "15-19", "20-24"), 
    table = list(structure(list(med_name_one = c("Co-amoxiclav", 
    "doxycycline"), med_name_two = c(NA, "Gentamicin"), mg_one = c("411 mg", 
    "120 mg"), mg_two = c(NA, "11280 mg"), datetime = c("2020-01-03 10:08", 
    "2020-01-01 11:08"), date_time = structure(c(1578046080, 
    1577876880), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), structure(list(med_name_one = c("Gentamicin", "Co-trimoxazole"
    ), med_name_two = c("Co-trimoxazole", NA), mg_one = c("11280 mg", 
    "8 mg"), mg_two = c("8 mg", NA), datetime = c("2020-01-02 19:08", 
    "2020-01-08 20:08"), date_time = structure(c(1577992080, 
    1578514080), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), structure(list(med_name_one = "Gentamicin", med_name_two = NA_character_, 
        mg_one = "11280 mg", mg_two = NA_character_, datetime = "2020-01-02 19:08", 
        date_time = structure(1577992080, tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), structure(list(med_name_one = "Co-trimoxazole", med_name_two = NA_character_, 
        mg_one = "8 mg", mg_two = NA_character_, datetime = "2020-01-08 20:08", 
        date_time = structure(1578514080, tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), structure(list(med_name_one = "Sodium Chloride", med_name_two = NA_character_, 
        mg_one = "411 mg", mg_two = NA_character_, datetime = "2020-01-10 08:08", 
        date_time = structure(1578643680, tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), structure(list(med_name_one = "Piperacillin", med_name_two = NA_character_, 
        mg_one = "120 mg", mg_two = NA_character_, datetime = "2020-01-03 09:08", 
        date_time = structure(1578042480, tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L)), structure(list(med_name_one = character(0), med_name_two = character(0), 
        mg_one = character(0), mg_two = character(0), datetime = character(0), 
        date_time = structure(numeric(0), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), 
        structure(list(med_name_one = character(0), med_name_two = character(0), 
            mg_one = character(0), mg_two = character(0), datetime = character(0), 
            date_time = structure(numeric(0), tzone = "Europe/London", class = c("POSIXct", 
            "POSIXt"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
        ), row.names = integer(0)))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to map a variable from the list (table). The variable is called med_name_one.

```
get_medication_name <- function(medication_name_df) {
  
  medication_name <- medication_name_df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(datetime) %>%
    pull(med_name_one)
}
```

Here I am applying the function so that I get the `med_name_one` as a variable.

```
age_pharma <- mutate(medication_name = purrr::map(age_pharma, get_medication_name))
```

Yet I do not know why I get this error?

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `medication_name`.
x Result 1 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 2
ℹ Input `medication_name` is `purrr::map_chr(table, get_medication_name)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can someone help me understand the error? Also how can I retrieve med_name_one?

Comment: So what is the variable name for the sample data you provided? Is that `age_pharma`? You seem to be using `mutate()` without a data parameter which is unusual. Are you trying to `map` over the `table` column? I don't see any values with the name `medication_name` so I'm not sure what you are trying to distract. What exactly is the desired output for the sample input?

Comment: @MrFlick - I have re-edited the post. Because I realise I confuse but also had some terminology mistakes. The data parameter is age_pharma. I have forgotten to define is as an object as I used dput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option

```
get_medication_name <- function(medication_name_df) {
  
  medication_name <- medication_name_df %>%
    dplyr::arrange(datetime) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(medname = first(med_name_one)) %>%
    dplyr::pull(medname)
}

age_pharma %>% mutate(medication_name = purrr::map_chr(table, get_medication_name))
```

First we had to change the `get_medication_name` function to handle the case where there are no rows in the table column which is the case in your example.

Then we need to apply the `map` specifically to the table column.

Comment: it does work but this solution doesn't account for the second medication done on the same patient. I have actually (again) re-edited the post and done the changes needed, where I have first and second id have multiple medication given. Thus, I am hoping to get a solution that accounts for the second medication given to 1st and 2nd id. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be much easier if you had provided the desired output for your sample input. That way we can easily check if a solution returns the correct answer or not.

Comment: I know, I have just realised I have not accounted for the second medication given. I do apologies